# Performance of Symbols vs number literal?

Tags: javascript

I've been using object literals as a poor man's enum, something like this:

```
let enum = {
    option1: Symbol("o1"),
    option2: Symbol("o2"),
    option3: Symbol("o3")
};

let item = enum.option2;

if(item === enum.option2) { console.log("Item is Option 2!") }
```

I use `Symbol` because I think it makes more semantic sense than using numbers -- in this case I don't really care about which value the "enum" carries, I just want to check equality -- but am slightly worried about performance considerations of doing it that way. Am I putting a bigger strain on the processor if I keep using Symbols in place of integers?

Comment: You could use plain objects, but unless you're making extreme use of many many thousands of such values it's going to make no difference at all to performance.

Comment: context matters with performance. run your own tests at JSPerf and tell us what you find

Comment: The biggest strain on the processor is the fact that you are using JavaScript. It's going to be slow anyway, so do what makes the most sense in the context of your project.

Comment: `but am slightly worried about performance considerations of doing it that way.` that's a classic case of premature optimisation. *Is it* a problem? Chances are it won't be, as I suspect you won't be running that code too often. Even if you are, the JS interpreter might optimise it for you on the fly. It's really hard to say whether or not this will impact performance as it seems like something completely trivial. It's not like an algorithm you can clearly find the complexity for and know you'd be calling it for, say, 30% of the processing time.

Comment: Have you profiled your application to determine if this is an actual issue? It seems almost completely unlikely that this will have significant negative impact even if it *was* slightly slower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, symbols are primitive values just like numbers and should be compared equally fast. The only downside might be that you have to use a variable to refer to them instead of a trusted literal, but if your variables are `const` and never assigned, an optimising compiler should be able to inline symbol values as well.

In any case, you should definitely use what makes more sense semantically, and helps you with development performance. Execution speed is secondary, and the difference here will be negligible.